# Error while creating view with 'with' statements DB2

Tags: sql, view, db2, common-table-expression, db2-400

I am trying to compile following view

```
create view MY_VIEW as
with 
WITH_DATA as
(
     select ID_TECH
     from CLC_TABLE
     where 1 = (select 1 as kol from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)
)
select * from WITH_DATA
where exists (select 1 from WITH_DATA);
```

The error is:

> Error: [SQL0901] SQL system error. Cause . . . . . :   An SQL system error has occurred.  The current SQL statement cannot be completed successfully.  The error will not prevent other SQL statements from being processed. Previous messages may indicate that there is a problem with the SQL statement and SQL did not correctly diagnose the error. The previous message identifier was .Internal error type 4266 has occurred. If precompiling, processing will not continue beyond this statement. Recovery  . . . :   See the previous messages to determine if there is a problem with the SQL statement. To view the messages, use the DSPJOBLOG command if running interactively, or the WRKJOB command to view the output of a precompile.  An application program receiving this return code may attempt further SQL statements.  Correct any errors and try the request again.
>
> SQLState:  58004
>
> ErrorCode: -901

When I try to run the select without creating the view everything works fine. But when I tr to create the view the error listed above occurs.

Do not try to understand the logic of above view. I just simplified my query to show the source of the error.

DB2 6.1. AS/400

Comment: Could try wrapping with a select around whole thing ,just a wild guess

Comment: Looks to be severely overengineered.  It also appears to select all the records from the clc_table, no matter what.

Comment: Thanks for anwers. I know it select all from CLC_TABLE. But the question is about the reason of the error.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the SQL processor, if you comment out the where clause in in the outer select, it creates properly. Maybe open a PMR with IBM. BTW, this happens at 7.1 as well, but I have never come across it in production cases. Maybe you can show us the real SQL you are having trouble with.

Comment: Thanks for your answear. I also noticed, that commenting out the outer where clause resolve the problem. Also the funny thing is, that instead of commenting out the outer clause, it is enough to replace  'where 1 = (select 1 as kol from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)' with 'where 1 = 1'. Then it also works fine. The real sql is quite big, more than 100 lines and contains lots of 'with' parts. Presented sql is just simplified version of my full sql. I will try to find workaround this problem. I just thought that there is a reasonable bug in my sql. I will also open PMR to IBM with that issue.